# SQL error when trying to save product

Tags: error, sql, foreign-key

There is an integrety violation when I try to save a product. I did some searches and some suggested to join tables and check for null values. I tried that without luck. How can I solve/debug this?

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`catalog_product_entity_int`,
CONSTRAINT`FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN
KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)
ON D)' in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

Comment: i guess you done reindexing.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I don't know what you mean exactly, but it's not an indexing issue afaik, i just did a reindex and tried to save the product again to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem once.

The problem was an extention I had installed which wrote sql. The problem was sth with innodb databases...

Anyway navigate through the database and find if there is a relation "FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID" in any custom tables so you can find which extention tables causing the problem. Then either disable the module or remove the relation. 
Always backup!